# simply execution command to save log report as per test case name

Tags: robotframework

I am using following command to execute script at pycharm terminal

```
robot -d Output --loglevel TRACE --report TC001report.html --log TC001log.html --output TC001output.xml TestCases\TC001.robot
```

the command is very long, any good method to run this so I do not have to hit different command for each test case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify by moving the `-d Output` and the `--loglevel TRACE` into an [argument file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#argument-files). Effectively replacing them with `-A common_args.txt`.

You can further simplify by [creating-start-up-script](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-start-up-scripts).

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from robot import run_cli

tc_name = sys.argv[1]
run_cli(['-d', 'Output', '--loglevel', 'TRACE', '--report', f'{tc_name}report.html', '--log', f'{tc_name}log.html', '--output', f'{tc_name}output.xml', f'TestCases\{tc_name}.robot'], exit=False)
```

Use it: `python launch.py TC001`.

Comment: just to clarify, so i named the file launch.py and put it at the root path ?

Comment: @guo Yes, project root.